# Android & Object Output Stream: A standoff

Tags: java, android, objectoutputstream

The purpose of the app is to simply send a string object to the server on my machine. All port forwarding configurations are set as I tested the server with a java client on my machine.

Problem lies in talking to the server from android client. Server seems never to be hit.

Basic rundown of the app: Simple screen with 1 button & 1 textview. Button sends object to server, server responds with message, which updates the textview. As I've said, the server never seems to be hit. Anyone have any ideas what I can do to fix this?

```
public class ObjectTestActivity extends Activity {

Button submit;
private String string = "Hello Android";
private ObjectOutputStream oos;
private ObjectInputStream ois;
private final int PORT = 3000;

TextView tv;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    try{

        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Socket socket = new Socket("xx.xx.xxx.xxx", PORT);

        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    }catch(UnknownHostException e){}
     catch(IOException e){}
}


public void onClick(View view){

    try{
        oos.writeObject(string);
        String serverMsg = (String) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        oos.close();
                    tv.setText("Message from Server: " + serverMsg);
    }catch(IOException e){}
     catch(ClassNotFoundException e){}
}
```

}

Comment: can you post the permissions from your Manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Try testing your android client code from a simple java client first. If that works at least you know its a android issue.

And then look at your manifest file. You need "android.permission.INTERNET".

You are not printing the stacktrace on the Exceptions in the onCreate, so there is no way to know if a exception occurred.

Also try using a higher port number 32344 maybe.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by a simple java client - as in a simple ping to the server? I have set the Android permissions to INERNET from the beginning so that is not the issue.